# Gnumeric tables to latex

Tags: latex, gnumeric

I've been using Gnumeric's functionality to export tables to be usable in LaTeX. My question is if there is an easy way to locally change the font size fot hose tables.

My tables are quite complex (produced by SPSS actually, but that's another problem, I have no choice producing them in this way, hopefully for not too long). What I do is "export other format", then choose "LaTeX", not "fragment...". This gives a file that can be compiled on its own, but that can also be included (using \input{}) in my main LaTeX file. Some minor adjustments are neede in order this to work (load packages...). However, for some reason nothing happens when, for instance I do 
\begin{small}
\input{} 
\end{small}. 
I tried changing the fonts size in Gnumeric, without any result.

The tables I get are way too big, I would like to have then in \small size or even \footnotesize, ithout affecting the font size for the main document.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Anything here help? [How to decrease the font size of a table in an \input file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34438/how-to-decrease-the-font-size-of-a-table-in-an-input-file)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I came to a somehow similar solution using [this](http://texblog.org/2012/08/29/changing-the-font-size-in-latex/)